# How to exclude latest x posts from a paginated query?

Tags: posts, wp-query, loop, query-posts, pre-get-posts

I have a WordPress loop, that is part of an AJAX call. Every time a button is clicked, this function is called, runs the below loop and outputs the next 6 posts. There are already five posts shown by default. How can I exclude the five latest (most recent published) posts from the Wordpress loop? So that page 1 of the loop starts with the 6th, 7th, 8th, 9th, 10th & 11th post?

This is the loop that I use. It would be great if someone could tell me how to alter it so that it starts with the 6th post. Thanks in advance!

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
    'paged' => $paged, //Starts with 1 (or a different number if that's better)
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
?>

<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>

        <div class="amb-home-post-single override">
            <div class="amb-home-post-contents override">       
                <img class="amb-home-thumbnail-container override" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>">
                <h2><a href='<?php the_permalink() ?>'><?php the_title() ?></a></h2>
                <div class="amb-home-post content override"><?php the_excerpt() ?></div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use the `offset` parameter in `WP_Query`, but it overrides the `paged` parameter according to the [docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

**Example formula for an offset with pagination:**

```
'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
'offset'         => ( $paged - 1 ) * $posts_per_page + $offset_per_page,
```

**Example:**

Then for `$posts_per_page` as 4 and `$offset_per_page` as 5 we get the post numbers:

```
first page:   6,7,8,9    (skip first 5 posts)
second page: 10,11,12,13 (skip first 9 posts)
third page:  14,15,16,17 (skip first 13 posts)
...
```

**Notes:**

In [this previous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/237427/pagination-adding-extra-posts-only-on-page-2/237457#237457) I've added a way to play with another type of formula.

There might be some [performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1243952/how-can-i-speed-up-a-mysql-query-with-a-large-offset-in-the-limit-clause) for really large offset numbers.

Note that WordPress also has it's own REST API that can in many cases be used instead of Ajax.

I also wonder if the offset is really needed here, if the original loop + Ajax can be replaced with a single REST API setup instead.

ps: above is untested.

Comment: Hi @birgire thanks for your helping! I'm going to test it tomorrow, I'll let you know and mark your answer as correct if I get it working.

Comment: I was curious if it it would work so I made some time so I could try it ;). And it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear it helped